# DataGridView Can not change foreground color

Tags: .net, datagridview, user-controls

I have created a User Control with a DataGridView, every time I try to change the foreground color to black, it changes back to white when I save it. When I re-open the User Control I can see that is has changed back to white but if I don't close it and change it to black, it stays that color. The background color does work, I tried to set it to maroon and it saved it. How come it keeps changing the foreground color to white? I have not added any code to do this.

Comment: How are you changing the color?

Comment: In the properties I'm trying to change the DefaultCellStyle forecolor to black but after saving it, it changes back to white @RodrigoRodrigues